Can’t get cardano-wallet to work
I’m trying to get cardano-wallet to run on a local server to test out an application that I’m working on. I’m interested in using the wallet backend API. I had an issue while trying to build cardano-node from source so I’ve resorted to using the docker containers for both the node and wallet.
Command to run cardano-node:
sudo docker run \
--rm \
-v ./preview_testnet_node_config:/configuration \
-p 1337:1337 \
ghcr.io/intersectmbo/cardano-node:8.9.2 run \
--topology /configuration/topology.json \
--database-path /configuration/db \
--socket-path /configuration/db/preview_testnet_node.socket \
--host-addr 0.0.0.0 \
--port 1337 \
--config /configuration/config.json

This seems to work fine. I’m getting some errors but they don’t seem fatal (please correct me if I’m wrong).
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrInboundGovernorCounters (InboundGovernorCounters {coldPeersRemote = 3, idlePeersRemote = 2, warmPeersRemote = 0, hotPeersRemote = 0})
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 4, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 1, outboundConns = 3})
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrDemotedToColdRemote (ConnectionId {localAddress = 172.17.0.2:1337, remoteAddress = 3.70.89.92:3001}) (OperationSuccess CommitTr)
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrInboundGovernorCounters (InboundGovernorCounters {coldPeersRemote = 3, idlePeersRemote = 1, warmPeersRemote = 0, hotPeersRemote = 0})
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 3, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 3})
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrDemotedToColdRemote (ConnectionId {localAddress = 172.17.0.2:1337, remoteAddress = 18.185.163.167:3001}) (OperationSuccess CommitTr)
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:73] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.44 UTC] TrInboundGovernorCounters (InboundGovernorCounters {coldPeersRemote = 3, idlePeersRemote = 0, warmPeersRemote = 0, hotPeersRemote = 0})
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:28.50 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 462d0cd0e1cbcffb3f0ed3c0f7f0d3d66244c6ce08963f49686d3eb5ef9512cd at slot 50139156
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:29.75 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: cb232af3ed7c2b521d6efd8b0ef53f1d9d9ddc4fa41261d76af872627b379319 at slot 50143366
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:31.01 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 45e8830219d76c701e94cf9cdcc924b8421e2f17fc1ddbf3fe66ad32b89900a7 at slot 50147299
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:32.26 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 4d5e68d3d8ee562b72f2a700903bd01110824ed99f60e4abb43b26b84d915c5d at slot 50150025
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:33.51 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 2cca1fdad991a47027d146ccad7af962ebb08aaa5bb47cc679daf659ae073403 at slot 50154444
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:34.76 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: b2c757fac985ccc61df338de2916f88d5b3a33efcd76a4c08eed29b044f18650 at slot 50158674
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:36.02 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 16b857160b39a4ef11fb8823d15e624ae6c756a0b1866394945ba6004d887089 at slot 50161192
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:37.31 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: e9fda28d1c4b80dbd60fccc5421d80f5976bf6e56ec705fb68722acc76d3faad at slot 50165298
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:38.56 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 9ebe02da870c040a070d3041968532301ed635085fe8366f2e837a3aa4d227a9 at slot 50168583
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:47] [2024-05-28 01:38:38.87 UTC] Took ledger snapshot DiskSnapshot {dsNumber = 50120552, dsSuffix = Nothing} at a6b8a1f9e57b8c4e36b8bad359815e4403f2fd4532b7e80504f86482f96df727 at slot 50120552
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:38.88 UTC] Valid candidate f43534e2576440e86c5013ed5bdb88ee40b7fa9068a2ee74fbd33b540b83345b at slot 50169560
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:38.88 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: f43534e2576440e86c5013ed5bdb88ee40b7fa9068a2ee74fbd33b540b83345b at slot 50169560
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:38.96 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 15d99ac48cd62e895c7f891966a0fee8f4b8a1ca9a3692182ed1629fe5521ab8 at slot 50169594
[d0953d4d:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:43] [2024-05-28 01:38:40.23 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 319c6f4689259b54f5d3ddf21bf74339367c60800022ed42e9d3351640e06fad at slot 50176686

Command to run cardano-wallet:
sudo docker run \
--rm \
-v ./preview_testnet_node_config:/configuration \
-p 8090:8090 \
cardanofoundation/cardano-wallet:latest serve \
--port 8090 \
--node-socket /configuration/db/preview_testnet_node.socket \
--testnet /configuration/byron-genesis.json \
--database /configuration/wallet_db \
--token-metadata-server https://metadata.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io

I see what seem to be network errors, but from looking online, others get the same errors without any effect on the wallet’s operation.
[cardano-wallet.pools-engine:Info:38] [2024-05-26 19:10:46.76 UTC] Still in sync. Applied 10 blocks, 0 rollbacks in the last 300.001243712s. Current tip is [point f0833601 at slot 50094608].
[cardano-wallet.ntp-client:Notice:122] [2024-05-26 19:10:48.78 UTC] ntp client experienced error Network.Socket.ByteString.sendManyTo: does not exist (Network unreachable) when sending packet
[cardano-wallet.ntp-client:Notice:123] [2024-05-26 19:10:49.88 UTC] ntp client experienced timeout using IPv6 protocol

In my case, however, I can’t seem to get any response when I try to use the wallet API.
Trying from localhost:
mohamed@austin:~$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8090/v2/network/information
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
mohamed@austin:~$ curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8090/v2/network/information
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
mohamed@austin:~$ netstat -ltn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1337            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::1337                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

Trying from system on local network:
mohamed@sahara-dev:~$ curl -X GET http://192.168.2.61:8090/v2/network/information
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.61 port 8090 after 3 ms: Connection refused
mohamed@sahara-dev:~$ ping 192.168.2.61
PING 192.168.2.61 (192.168.2.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.99 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=2.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=2.38 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=2.40 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=3.46 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=3.85 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=2.29 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=2.72 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=2.91 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=10 ttl=63 time=2.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=11 ttl=63 time=2.34 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.61: icmp_seq=12 ttl=63 time=2.50 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.61 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 12 received, 0% packet loss, time 11022ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.288/2.730/3.845/0.469 ms
mohamed@sahara-dev:~$ curl -X GET http://192.168.2.61:8090/v2/network/information
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.61 port 8090 after 5 ms: Connection refused

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

The issue had to do with the port configuration with my docker containers. I was able to just download a release cardano-wallet package and run the node and wallet API directly from there without any issues (by using the same commands in my original post).

I recommend building cardano-node using Nix https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node-wiki/wiki/building-the-node-using-nix
Alternatively, use the cardano-cli directly with the environment configuration files. Same for cardano-wallet.
If you open a ticket  https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new you can receive support
